# Folder Mirroring onto NAS

Tags: windows-7, mirroring

I have a Win7 setup where I need to mirror, a local folder onto a NAS. I've tried Microsoft SyncToy but that is entirely too slow and produces inaccurate results. A requirement is that open files must be copied so Robocopy will not work. I believe the only way this will work is something that is built using VSS.

Comment: What are you going to do with the data on the NAS?  Are you trying to setup a backup, or will this data actually be used?

Comment: Potentially it will be used, so it has to be "live" data and not a compressed backup. Basically, we're doing a remote backup also but I want to mirror the folders locally so if there actually is an issue, we can failover to the NAS rather than wait for the 50+ gigs to download from the remote backup.